# Jquery Updating input field value [Replace the old value with the new value]

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the current code,when the button's clicked, it'll get the value from the done input and display them to the 3 input field respectively.

Let say i'd like to change the value in the done input field, and when the value is updated, the old values from the 3 input fields will be replaced by the new.
Now, the updated value just added after the original value instead of replacing it. What's wrong with my code guys?

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
if ( set ){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function(){
        $(this).val( $(this).val() + set );
    })
}
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 
    <td>
      <input type="button"  value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: remove this `$(this).val( $(this).val() + set );` and write this `$(this).val( set );` because `$(this).val( $(this).val() + set );` is adding values beside input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  if (set) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("data-value") + set);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text" data-value="hi">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text" data-value="hello">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text" data-value="sup">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

1. Add a data-* on each textarea.
2. Use that value instead of the actual value

Comment: glad to help happy coding mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(this).val( $(this).val(set));
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add `set` to `$(this).val()`, just update value to set using `$(this).val(set);`. something like this:

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
if ( set ){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function(){
        $(this).val(set);
    })
}
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 
    <td>
      <input type="button"  value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The thing is i have some prefilled text retrieve from the database that i'd like to keep, do u know how to on one hand keep those texts, while updating the value? Many thanks

Comment: you can access those values using `$(this).val()` before updating the values and store them in some variable.